# How do I resolve an azure connection error - Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-cognitive-search, azure-python-sdk

I am trying to follow a tutorial on building a langchain chatbot on azure:
LangChain on Microsoft Azure - ChatBot with Azure Web Service & Azure Cognitive Search
https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=WAedZvSDZAI

I am getting an error when I run: "python azurecognitive_search.py"
I am able to run "python blob.py"

These are the python libraries I am using with Python 3.11.5
azure-common 1.1.28
azure-core 1.29.4
azure-graphrbac 0.61.1
azure-identity 1.14.0
azure-mgmt-authorization 3.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry 10.1.0
azure-mgmt-core 1.4.0
azure-mgmt-keyvault 10.2.3
azure-mgmt-network 21.0.1
azure-mgmt-resource 22.0.0
azure-mgmt-storage 21.0.0
azure-search-documents 11.4.0b8
azure-storage-blob 12.18.1
azureml 0.2.7
azureml-core 1.53.0

However, I get the following error when I run: "python azurecognitive_search.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lindq\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Azure\AzureChatbot\LangChain-On-Azure\azurecognitive_search.py", line 17, in 
vector_store: AzureSearch = AzureSearch(
^^^^^^^^^^^^
…
…
File "C:\Users\lindq\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\transport_requests_basic.py", line 381, in send
raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002E05E02DD50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

The azurerecognition_search.py follows:

```
import os
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.azuresearch import AzureSearch
from langchain.document_loaders import AzureBlobStorageContainerLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

model: str = "text-embedding-ada-002"

vector_store_address: str = f"https://${os.environ.get('AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_SERVICE_NAME')}.search.windows.net"


embeddings: OpenAIEmbeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(deployment=model, chunk_size=1)
index_name: str = "langchain-vector-demo"
vector_store: AzureSearch = AzureSearch(
    azure_search_endpoint=vector_store_address,
    azure_search_key=os.environ.get("AZURE_COGNITIVE_SEARCH_API_KEY"),
    index_name=index_name,
    embedding_function=embeddings.embed_query,
)

loader = AzureBlobStorageContainerLoader(
    conn_str=os.environ.get("AZURE_CONN_STRING"),
    container=os.environ.get("CONTAINER_NAME"),
)
documents = loader.load()

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=150, chunk_overlap=20)
docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
vector_store.add_documents(documents=docs)

print("Data loaded into vectorstore successfully")
```

I have tried

Install Azure Cognitive Search SDK
pip install azure-search-documents==11.4.0b8
pip install azure-identity

The first message in the traceback is related to
`vector_store: AzureSearch = AzureSearch(`

So I was hoping that might fix the issue.

The last message in the traceback is related to "Failed to establish a new connection:"
So I installed:
Azure Developer CLI in VS Code

And then I used the CLI interface to signin:

Then use the Azure Development CLI to signin
View
== Command Palatte
== Azure Developer CLI (azd) Sign in with Azure Developer CLI

And reran python azurecognitive_search.py

with the same error...

Comment: see this youtube video `langchain` before you proceed: https://youtu.be/ygehmBjwtiw

Comment: From medium, it seems that langchain.vectorstores.azuresearch error is indicitive of a wrong langchain version, ACS and retrivers, we need to use version **0.0.271**

I have tried pip install langchain[all] and then tried:
pip install langchain==0.0.271
But when I do
pip show langchain
it shows me a bunch of packages required and when I install them one at a time it still shows them as required.  And I still get the  langchain.vectorstores.azuresearch error

Comment: I have also upgraded the following:
pip install azure-search-documents --pre --upgrade.
pip install azure-search --pre --upgrade
pip install azure-core --pre --upgrade
pip install azure-identity --pre --upgrade

My error is now:
ImportError: cannot import name 'VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models'

Comment: HI @Erik Lindquist
 did you solve this problem 
if yes then show us